# Android Studio : View iteration returning null

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem trying to put views into an arrayList with a loop.

This works:

```
String textV = "chkBox1Text";
int textI = getResources().getIdentifier(textV, "id", getPackageName());
TextView test = (TextView)findViewById(textI);
test.setText("Test 01");
```

However this

```
ArrayList<TextView> friendNames = new ArrayList<TextView>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        String textViewID = "chkBox" + i+1 + "Text";
        int current = getResources().getIdentifier(textViewID, "id", getPackageName());
        TextView currentTV = (TextView)findViewById(current);
        friendNames.add(currentTV);
    }
friendNames.get(0).setText("Test 01");  // 0 or 1
```

Returns a null pointer exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   ******.FriendActivity.onCreate(FriendActivity.java:56)

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: You should check the values of `textViewID` in the loop. You'll see what the problem is.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid... Can't believe I missed that. Thank you Mike. It's not adding the i+1 only concatenating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie Mistake,

```
 String textViewID = "chkBox" + i+1 + "Text";
```

Should really be

```
 String textViewID = "chkBox" + (i+1) + "Text";
```

Thanks to Mike M

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to confirm, but I think your problem is that perhaps:

```
friendNames.add((TextView)findViewById(currentTV));
```

should just be:

```
friendNames.add(currentTV);
```

since `currentTV` is already a TextView, which you found in the previous line.

Comment: Ah sorry, fixed that. It was just a typo of mine in the code. It is how you put it. Thanks